# pandas sqlite - No such column with variable

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am using pd.read_sql_query to take data from sqlite to pandas. No surprises but the below works as expected.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('AmApp.db')
sql = """SELECT * FROM clients WHERE first_name='john'""", conn)
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
print (df)
```

However as soon as I add a variable into first name, as below, I get the error:

pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE first_name=john': no such column: john

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('AmApp.db')
sql = """SELECT * FROM clients WHERE first_name={}""".format('john'))
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
print (df
```

I do not quite understand where i am going wrong with this.

Comment: TRY THIS ```sql = """SELECT * FROM clients WHERE first_name='{}'""".format('john'))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the value:

```
sql = """ SELECT * FROM clients WHERE first_name='{}' """.format('john'))
```